# Problem Sending Email With Attachment And Queue In Laravel 6.0

Tags: laravel-6, laravel-mail, laravel-jobs

I have problem with send email with attachment. The problem is when i put the send email inside job and when i running it, it show an error like:

> Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed

Any Solutions?

> My Job File 'SendEmailCovernote.php'

```
public $email, $data, $pdf, $doc_numb_covernote, covernote_created_at;
public function __construct($email, $data, $pdf, $doc_numb_covernote, $covernote_created_at)
{
  $this->email = $email;
  $this->data = $data;
  $this->pdf = $pdf;
  $this->doc_numb_covernote = $doc_numb_covernote;
  $this->covernote_created_at = $covernote_created_at;
}
public function handle()
{
  Mail::send('email.covernote_content', ['Body' => $data], function($message) use ($email, $pdf, $doc_numb_covernote, $covernote_created_at)
  {
   $message->from('support@jcr.com');
   $message->subject('Pengiriman Covernote');
   $message->attachData($pdf, $doc_numb_covernote.'_facultative_covernote_'.Str::slug($covernote_created_at, '_').'.pdf');
   $message->to($email);
  });
}
```

> My Controller

```
use App\Jobs\SendEmailCovernote;
use PDF;
public function store(Request $request)
{
  //Some Other Code
  $data['covernote'] = CoverNote::where('id', $covernote->id)->first();
  $rsc_id = $data['covernote']->closing_instruction->confirmation_sent->id;
  $data['total_rate_agreed'] = 'Some Other Data';
  $pdf = PDF::loadView('risk_covering.covernote.print4', $data)->setPaper('a4', 'portrait');
  $doc_numb_covernote = $data['covernote']->document_number;
  $covernote_created_at = date('M d, Y', strtotime($data['covernote']->created_at));
  $email = $covernote->closing_instruction->crm_contact->email;
  SendEmailCovernote::dispatch($data, $email, $pdf, $doc_numb_covernote, $covernote_created_at);
}
```

Note: I'm using library dompdf to generate pdf file.